# App is getting crash in iOS if we open control centre in React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, ecmascript-6, crash, control-center

We are doing React Native Application. It is working fine in both iOS and Android. But, After launching application, If we open the Control Centre, The app is getting crash.

console data is follows

```
Error: {
    message = "Entries must be arrays of the form [key: string, value: string], got: (\n    InActiveTime\n)";
}
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: Please provide crash log.

Comment: @Manish Added console data, Please check once.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I have found the issue.

The issue is we are storing some key value in Asyncstorage, There we are storing Date. That Date data type not able to storing in Asyncstorage.
So, We can store Asyncstorage only **String** type as per I understand.

Hope this will help someone in future.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem(time, new Date().toString());
```